# Перенос элементов списка на следующую строку по номеру элемента. Python

Tags: python, строки, list, перенос

Всем привет. У меня есть список:

```
c = ['qwe', 'asd', 'zxc', 'qwerty']
```

Я не знаю заранее какие значения будут в списке. Но хочу при выводе в print сделать перенос строки после 2 элемента. То есть вот так:

```
qwe asd
zxc qwerty
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: print(*[' '.join(c[i:i + 2]) for i in range(0, len(c), 2)], sep='\n')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После каждого второго элемента будет перевод строки

```py
c = ['qwe', 'asd', 'zxc', 'qwerty']

for count in range(len(c)):
    print(c[count], end=" ")
    if count % 2 != 0:
        print()
```

Comment: Как по мне создание отдельной переменной ```count``` вне ```for``` излишне. Лучше сделать ```for count in range(len(c)):```

Comment: Справедливо. Изменил ответ